# Can you specify other descriptor attributes using object literal notation in javascript (ECMAScript5)?

Tags: javascript, json

I've seen that can use object literal notation to define an object with a getter like so:

```
var foo = {
            get bar() { return 3; }
          }
```

Is there some object literal syntax that allows me to set other property descriptor attributes of "bar" above, such as 'enumerable'?

Or, is '**get/set**' the only property descriptor attributes supported for ECMAScript5 object literal notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good question...but I don't think it can be done.

`get` and `set` are defined as operators that act the same way as [property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(foo, "bar", {value : 3,  
                                   writable : true,  
                                   enumerable : true,  
                                   configurable : true,
                                   get : function(){ return value; },  
                                   set : function(newValue){ value = newValue;}
                                  });
```

Looking through the javascript [operator list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) I don't see anything similar for other descriptors apart from get and set.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're gonna have to use `Object.defineProperty`.

This is what [the specs](http://es5.github.com/#A.3) say:

> **ObjectLiteral:**
>
> ```
> { }
> { PropertyNameAndValueList }
> { PropertyNameAndValueList , }
> ```
>
> **PropertyNameAndValueList:**
>
> ```
> PropertyAssignment
> PropertyNameAndValueList , PropertyAssignment
> ```
>
> **PropertyAssignment:**
>
> ```
> PropertyName : AssignmentExpression
> get PropertyName() { FunctionBody }
> set PropertyName( PropertySetParameterList ) { FunctionBody }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you may also want to use is the setter syntax, but you've probably known that.

Some browsers support a `__proto__` property that lets you set an objects prototype, but it's not specified and might be removed every day.

Use it like a regular property name:

```
var foo = {
    __proto__: bar
};
```